# Toggle button not working the second time is used

Tags: android, android-studio

this is my code:

```
public void gotoalbanian (View view) {
    if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("selectedlanguage", "Albanian");
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sharedPref.getString("selectedlanguage", null) + " is the default page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.browser);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    }
    else {
        setContentView(R.layout.browser);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    }
}
```

And this is the return button:

```
public void gotomain (View view) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        if (sharedPref.getString("selectedlanguage", null) != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sharedPref.getString("selectedlanguage", null) + " no longer default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.destroy();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    }
```

User can toggle a button so the app will save the selection, when I launch it and toggle the button so it will save, works fine but if I go back with `gotomain` and enable or disable the toggle button the outcome wont change, app will act however the button was before `gotomain` was used. If was enabled, will act enabled even if you disable it and vise versa.

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you call those 2 functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not working because you are providing a new layout to `setContentView`, (`setContentView(R.layout.browser);`). This will create a new View for your `Activity` making the hold reference not valid anymore. What you can do is to add the `WebView` to your "main" layout, the one you set in `onCreate` and change the visibility of its components accordingly to the state of your toggle button. If you have more complex use cases then, you should use `Fragment`s

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView` should only called once per Activity. Create your contentView in your onCreate function. Save a reference to your WebView as a property (and save the checked state, too).
Maybe try something like this:

```
private boolean isChecked = false;
private WebView myWebView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.browser);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    toggleButton = ??;
}

public void onResume() {
    toggleButton.setChecked(isChecked);
}

public void gotoalbanian (View view) {
    isChecked = toggleButton.isChecked();
    if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("selectedlanguage", "Albanian");
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sharedPref.getString("selectedlanguage", null) + " is the default page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    } else {
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    }
}

public void gotomain (View view) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    if (sharedPref.getString("selectedlanguage", null) != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sharedPref.getString("selectedlanguage", null) + " no longer default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.destroy();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```